# Re-index data frame; fill index using elements from multiple columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame as shown below:

```
            I1        V1         I2        V2         I3        V3    ...
0    13.823560  0.000000  13.639405  0.000000  13.455246  0.000000    ...
1    13.823376  0.001274  13.639224  0.001273  13.455068  0.001272    ...
2    13.823193  0.002547  13.639043  0.002546  13.454889  0.002544    ...
3    13.823009  0.003821  13.638862  0.003819  13.454711  0.003817    ...
4    13.822826  0.005095  13.638681  0.005092  13.454532  0.005089    ...
5    13.822642  0.006368  13.638500  0.006365  13.454354  0.006361    ...
...        ...       ...        ...       ...        ...       ...    ...
495   0.613282  0.630456   0.610912  0.630109   0.608497  0.629756    ... 
496   0.455202  0.631730   0.453456  0.631381   0.451677  0.631028    ... 
497   0.296663  0.633004   0.295533  0.632654   0.294383  0.632301    ...
498   0.137670  0.634277   0.137149  0.633927   0.136619  0.633573    ...  
499  -0.021770  0.635551  -0.021688  0.635200  -0.021605  0.634845    ...

[500 rows x 120 columns]
```

What I would like to do is reshape the DataFrame to make it look like this:

```
#(I as new index)
    I            V1          V2          V3          ...
    13.823560    0.000000    NaN         NaN         ...
    13.823376    0.001274    NaN         NaN         ...
    13.823193    0.002547    NaN         NaN         ...
    13.823009    0.003821    NaN         NaN         ...
    13.822642    0.005095    NaN         NaN         ...
    ...          ...         ...         ...         ...
     0.137670    0.630456    NaN         NaN         ...
     0.136619    NaN         NaN         0.633573    ...
    -0.021605    NaN         NaN         0.634845    ...
    -0.021688    NaN         0.635200    NaN         ...
    -0.021770    0.635551    NaN         NaN         ...

    [30000 rows x 60 columns]
```

In other words, I want to fill the new DataFrame index with all values encountered in all "I"-labeled columns (1 to 60 in my case). However, I also want to keep the remaining V-columns untouched for now - as long as they still link to their original I-counterpart value.

When trying the following ...

```
dfen = pd.melt(dfen, id_vars=['I'+str(b) for b in xrange(1,len(irlist)+1)], var_name='id', value_name='V')
```

... the DataFrame is squeezed to just two columns, so I think I will need something trickier.

Anyone any idea how to re-index the DataFrame in the way shown above?

The function will be called a lot of times, so speed optimization is quite important as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with:

```
Int64Index: 11 entries, 0 to 10
Data columns (total 6 columns):
I1    11 non-null float64
V1    11 non-null float64
I2    11 non-null float64
V2    11 non-null float64
I3    11 non-null float64
V3    11 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(6)
```

Try:

```
pd.concat([df.loc[:, ['V{}'.format(i), 'I{}'.format(i)]].rename(columns={'I{}'.format(i): 'I'}) for i in range(1, 4)])
```

to get:

```
            I        V1        V2        V3
0   13.823560  0.000000       NaN       NaN
1   13.823376  0.001274       NaN       NaN
2   13.823193  0.002547       NaN       NaN
3   13.823009  0.003821       NaN       NaN
4   13.822826  0.005095       NaN       NaN
5   13.822642  0.006368       NaN       NaN
6    0.613282  0.630456       NaN       NaN
7    0.455202  0.631730       NaN       NaN
8    0.296663  0.633004       NaN       NaN
9    0.137670  0.634277       NaN       NaN
10  -0.021770  0.635551       NaN       NaN
0   13.639405       NaN  0.000000       NaN
1   13.639224       NaN  0.001273       NaN
2   13.639043       NaN  0.002546       NaN
3   13.638862       NaN  0.003819       NaN
4   13.638681       NaN  0.005092       NaN
5   13.638500       NaN  0.006365       NaN
6    0.610912       NaN  0.630109       NaN
7    0.453456       NaN  0.631381       NaN
8    0.295533       NaN  0.632654       NaN
9    0.137149       NaN  0.633927       NaN
10  -0.021688       NaN  0.635200       NaN
0   13.455246       NaN       NaN  0.000000
1   13.455068       NaN       NaN  0.001272
2   13.454889       NaN       NaN  0.002544
3   13.454711       NaN       NaN  0.003817
4   13.454532       NaN       NaN  0.005089
5   13.454354       NaN       NaN  0.006361
6    0.608497       NaN       NaN  0.629756
7    0.451677       NaN       NaN  0.631028
8    0.294383       NaN       NaN  0.632301
9    0.136619       NaN       NaN  0.633573
10  -0.021605       NaN       NaN  0.634845
```

Comment: Is it also possible to acquire the same DataFrame, but then with NaN's instead of copies for the V-columns on (row,column) values that were not interlinked in the original DataFrame? (e.g. I=13.823560 only matching with V1 = 0.000000, the other two (V2,V3) as NaN's)

Comment: See updated - is this closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - great! Thanks a lot!